# Isomorphism R-module and quotient modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $A$ and $B$ submodules of $M$ such that $M=A\oplus B$.
>
> If $C$ and $D$ are submodules of $A$ and $B$, respectively and $N=C+D$,  then prove that:
>
> $$N=C\oplus D \text{ and } \frac{M}{N}=\frac{A\oplus B}{C \oplus D}\cong \frac{A}{C} \oplus \frac{B}{D}.$$

Is there an extension to this question? ( for part 2 )

Comment: Are you asking *us* whether there's an extension to **your** question? I think you meant to ask something else. but I don't know what.

Comment: both of them...
for part 1 we just prove that Subscription of C and D is null.
and for part 2 I think we must definition isomorphism function between left and right side of question... but i dont know What function should be defined . please help me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you meant to ask, but:

1) Clearly $\;C\cap D=\{0\}\;$ , and then $\;C+D=C\oplus D\;$

(2) First, observe that $\; A/C\oplus B/D\;$ is *the external* direct sum, and now define

$$\phi: M=A\oplus B\to A/C\oplus B/D\;,\;\;\phi(a,b):=\left(a+C\,,\,\,b+D\right)$$

Prove $\;\phi\;$ is an $\;R\,-$  modules homomorphism, and now find its kernel. Finally, use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: why phi function defined from $A$ $\oplus$ $B$ ?

Comment: @RezaYaghmaeian Because $\;A\oplus B=M\;$ , of course.

Comment: but we most defined phi function between $\frac{A $\oplus B}{C $\oplus D}  and $\frac{A}{C} $\oplus$ $\frac{B}{D}$

Comment: but we most defined phi function between

Comment: @RezaYaghmaeian No, **I defined** my function as I wanted to. Now **you must** apply the first isomorphism theorem and deduce what solves your problem.

Comment: I understood...
thank you .

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $f_i:M_i\rightarrow N_i$ is a homomorphism of R-modules for each $i\in I$, the homomorphism $$\begin{matrix}f:&\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i&\longrightarrow&\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i\in I}N_i\\&(x_i)_{i\in I}&\longmapsto&(f_i(x_i))_{i\in I}\end{matrix}$$ is such that $\displaystyle Ker(f)=\bigoplus_{i\in I}Ker(f_i)$ and $Im(f)=\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i\in I}Im(f_i)$. In particular, when $N_i$ is a submodule of $M_i$ and $f_i$ is the canonical projection $M_i\rightarrow\frac{M_i}{N_i}$ then $f$ is surjective and $$\frac{\displaystyle\oplus_{i\in I}M_i}{\displaystyle\oplus_{i\in I}N_i}=\frac{\oplus_{i\in I}M_i}{\oplus_{i\in I}Ker(f_i)}=\frac{\oplus_{i\in I}M_i}{Ker(f)}\simeq\bigoplus_{i\in I}\frac{M_i}{N_i}.$$